# How to access configuration beans in Spring controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application that uses Spring profiles to create environment specific configurations, for example:

```
@Configuration
@Profile("local")
public class LocalConfiguration
...

@Configuration
@Profile("prod")
public class ProdConfiguration
...
```

I have a @RestContoller that needs to access the values that the configurations load from `application.properties`. How can I inject the current environment specific configuration bean inside the controller?

Example:

```
@Autowired
private <config_based_on_env_here> config;

@RestController
public String getSomeString() {
    return config.getSomeString();
}
```

Comment: is your question resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to access values from the `application.properties` or `.yaml` configuration you could use a much simpler way for achieving this.

Firstly configure different configs:

`application-local.properties`

```
my.value=local-value
```

`application-prod.properties`

```
my.value=prod-value
```

Create a configuration for reading needed value:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my")
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    private String value;

    // standard getters and setters
}
```

Finally, you could autowire this configuration at the controller:

```
@RestController
class MyController {

    @Autowire
    private ConfigProperties config;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public void hello() {
      System.out.println("Config value: " + config.getValue()); 
    }
}
```

When you run your app with the needed profile - the appropriate config file will be loaded and accessed at the controller.

Also, you could have a look at [@Value](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation

***Additional resources***:

- [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)
- [Configuration properties in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot)
- [A Quick Guide to Spring @Value](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-value-annotation)

Comment: How does this approach work with the @Profile annotation? How does Spring know which configuration class to load if I don't annotate it with @Profile?

Comment: To to answer my own question Spring can load configurations based on the file names, for example if my active profile is "local" then it will search for application-{local}.yaml.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties

Comment: @tomtomssi you are right. However, your question is `How can I inject the current environment specific configuration bean inside the controller?` and I answer exactly this. You don't need to set up `@Profile` you could use general configuration -> value from which will depend on with which env you have launched the app (prod or local).

Comment: @tomtomssi my answer has a reference and suggestion have a look at `@Value` and has written earlier than one you accepted

Comment: Your solution was the correct one. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Spring keeps your configuration-based properties in an instance of the Environment class. If you keep your properties in files named application-local.properties and application-prod.properties you don't need to explicitly declare the beans as you have shown. Spring will pick the correct properties file based on the profile that is active. Inject the environment as follows:

```
@Autowired
private Environment config;
```

Comment: If you create an application.properties files it will be used and the properties in the profile specific files will override the values in the application.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the @Value annotation and access the property & @Configuration to specify from which file in whichever Spring bean you're using

At top of class add @Configuration

```
@Configuration("employeeProperties")
class YourClass{}
```

at usage you can add something like this

```
@Value("${userBucket.path}")
private String userBucketPath;
```

I hope, it helps